# Unknown class OTKTextChatView in Interface Builder file in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, opentok, tokbox

I have integrated TokBox for chatting functionality in my iOS app.

I have used this [link](https://tokbox.com/developer/components/text-chat/ios/)

this is my code

```
- (void)sessionDidConnect:(OTSession*)session {

    // When we've connected to the session, we can create the chat component.

    // crash on following line

    _textChat = [[OTKTextChatComponent alloc] init];

    _textChat.delegate = self;

    [_textChat setMaxLength:1050];
    [_textChat setSenderId:session.connection.connectionId alias:session.connection.data];

    CGRect r = self.view.bounds;
    r.origin.y += 20;
    r.size.height -= 20;
    [_textChat.view setFrame:r];
    [self.view addSubview:_textChat.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

    // fade in
    _textChat.view.alpha = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^() {
        //_connectingLabel.alpha = 0;
        _textChat.view.alpha = 1;
    }];

}
```

This demo is working perfectly. But when I am trying to integrate it in my project. It gives following error :

```
Unknown class OTKTextChatView in Interface Builder file.
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x7f8c43835fa0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 

this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key countLabel.'
    *** First throw call stack:
```

please help me

Comment: @Rumin now check ..bhai how r u?

Comment: M all good! Please add more details to your question.... to show the code where u r getting the crash using break points. So that people can help in u in proper way.

Comment: related to framework error

Comment: in a demo working good but when i add in my project then problem occur

Comment: Look like they launch a new one https://github.com/opentok/textchat-acc-pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `OTKTextChatView` class is not loaded before the xib loads (since it was in an external library). Normally we are setting `-all_load`, but in the documentation it says

> Do not use the `-all_load` linker flag. Instead, use the `-force_load`
>   linker flag to load specific libraries that require it.

If this doesn't help try to add the following code in your application did finish launching method

```
[OTKTextChatView class];
```

This will forcefully load `OTKTextChatView` class.

This will help you.

As per Maulik's suggestion:- 
Add this three library **OTKTextChatLibrary,OTKTextChatBundle & OTKTextChatBundle.bundle**..if you don't add this then this type error occur